# How to find the .hg/hgrc file on a mercurial bitbucket server

Tags: mercurial, hook, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket to host my main repository (using mercurial).I want to create an [incoming] hook but i cant find the .hg/hgrc file on bitbucket.I tried to create it but it won't accept it ( path contains illegal component ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to run arbitrary code on bitbucket so an "incoming hook" like that is not possible.

You are, however, allowed to set up webhooks, which means that bitbucket will talk to a server you set up whenever a push, or something else, happens.

To set up a webhook, do the following:

1. Navigate to your repository on the [bitbucket.org](http://www.bitbucket.org) website.
2. Open up the settings for your repository
3. Under "Integrations" (middle of the list), there is a section for "Webhooks".
4. Create a new webhook on this page